# UICollectionView drag & drop custom button trigger

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, drag

I have implemented the drag & drop feature on my collection view, everything is working perfectly.
I now need to trigger the drag with a button inside the cell rather than the default long press and I can't seem to find the method to notify the collection view that the dragging should start for the cell.

I've tried the `beginInteractiveMovementForItem` method but got nothing out of it.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more that how you used `beginInteractiveMovementForItem ` in your code?

Comment: I just called myCollectionView. beginInteractiveMovementForItem(at: indeIndexPath) upon tap on the button inside the cell, but it didn't worked